register a new user in keycloak using spring boot 3
I'm trying to make guests able to register in my spring boot app using keycloak without the need for a token.
I found this github repo where the spring boot app can sign in to keycloak with admin credentials and then guests can reach the spring boot app's endpoint for registering without the need for a token (because the spring boot app already got the token), but the only problem with this repo is that it's using deprecated dependencies (org.keycloak) that spring boot doesn't support anymore, so is there a newer way to get the keycloak instance in spring boot app and make spring boot app sign in (get the admin token) and register users ?

Any reason why users wouldn't use Keycloak built-in registration forms?

Seems to me like you want to use Keycloak but you don't want to use Keycloak

@ch4mp I want to build a custom form in angular rather than using  Keycloak built-in one

@Lukman I want to use Keycloak in a custom way, I want guests to be able to create new accounts using a custom angular form through API without the need for a token

I guess that you also want to use the password flow, in which case you'd better not use OAuth2, and so, something else than Keycloak: with OAuth2, user registration and login are made by the authorization server, not by the relying parties.
